# VSCODE and Visual Studio Android Emulator

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I am trying to connect visual studio android emulator with VSCode for flutter development, but cannot able to connect it. Is it possible to do so? If yes then how? I tried adding android-sdk path into registry, but didn't work. VSCode doesn't recognize the emulator.

Comment: Are you sure it's an issue with VSCode? Have you tried just using `flutter run`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting preinstalled genymotion and android emulator resolved the connection issue.